# Fiddle does not work when I use latest version of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does this fiddle just work when I use jQuery 1.5.2 ?

http://jsfiddle.net/azZVk/17/

[image]

When I set it to jQuery 1.7.2 nothing is displayed

[image]

With jQuery Mobile 1.0.1 unselected here is display :

[image]

Wheras this should be displayed :

[image]

Fiddle code :

```
<div data-role="page" id="firstpage">

        <div data-role="header">
                <h1>First Page</h1>
        </div>

<div data-role="content" id="links">

</div>

        <div data-role="footer">
                <h4>Page Footer</h4>
        </div>

</div>

<div data-role="page" id="secondpage">

        <div data-role="header">
                <a href='#' class='ui-btn-left' data-icon='arrow-l' onclick="history.back(); $('#pagecontent').empty(); return false">Back</a><h1>Bar</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="pagecontent" data-role="content">

        </div>

        <div data-role="footer">
                <h4>Page Footer</h4>
        </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {  
    $('#links').append(buildButton());     
}

   function buildButton() {
    var button= '<a data-role="button" href="#secondpage" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-up-c"><span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all"><span class="ui-btn-text">Link Button</span></span></a>';

    return $(button).click(function () {
        $("#secondpage").data("val", "test value")
    });       
   }

    $('#secondpage').live('pageshow', function() {
        var val1= $(this).data('val');
        $("#pagecontent").html(val1);
        console.log('val is '+ val1);
    });

});
```

Comment: Works fine for me.  What does your code look like?

Comment: Check the console and see if a javascript error is firing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you select `1.7.2`

you also ticked `Mobile 1.0.1`

**EDIT**: 
You are using wrong versions here

[image: In your Resources]

Update them to latest versions to work with 1.7.2

`CSS` : http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0jquery.mobile-1.1.0.css

and

`JS` :  http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js

to work with `1.7.2`  HERE :  http://jsfiddle.net/azZVk/25/

Also Dont use `live` us `on` instead.